# Eloquent update and event observers

Tags: laravel, lumen

I am making an API with lumen. I am trying to update entry and fire updated observer.
What I tried so far

```
$data = [];
$fota_device = Fota_device::find($deviceId);
$fota_device->update($data);
```

This code does not update database or fire updated event.

```
$data = [];
$fota_device = Fota_device::where('id', $deviceId);
$fota_device->update($data);
```

This code updates database but also does not fire the event.
I have read that eloquent does not fire updated events on mass assigns, but one of this way should at least fire the event but does not.

my observer

```
public function updated(Device $device)
{
    dd($fota_device);
    $user = Auth::user();
    $action = Users_action::create([
        'userId' => $user->id, 
        'created_at' => \Carbon\Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString()
    ]);
}
```

Why does first code sample not update the entry in the table and why could the observer not be fired?

Comment: did you register your observer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On `update`, it triggers only: `saving`, `saved` when it didn't modify anything;

This will NOT fire the `update` event because it's a [mass update](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#Updates):

```
$fota_device = Fota_device::where('id', $deviceId)->update(['fieldName' => $value]);
```

This will fire the update event if `$value` differ from the value from database:

```
User::find($id)->update(['fieldName' => $value]);
```

In your case, `$data = [];` is empty array and it didn't modify (update) anything;

Comment: In my Lumen 8.0 project the observers are working. but the 'updated' event only fires when there is at least one column has different value than db. if all the new $data has same value as DB then the `updated` event not firing. is this expected and any solution?